# How to add a filter to `tail -f` output that would issue an audible alarm given matching input?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, logging, zsh

I need to analyze a log for specific output and if a certain keyword is matched in the output, I need to issue an `echo -e "\a"`.

**How would I filter a script so that this would occur?**  I pass it through ack[-grep] as well so I'd like to put the alarm notification in prior to the colorization probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -f file | while read line; do
  echo $line | grep -qF keyword && echo -e \\a >&2; echo $line; done
```

This spawns more processes than sed, but puts the control character on the terminal via stderr so that it is less likely to be modified by downstream processes.  Also, it is entirely possible for an implementation of sed to buffer its input and not generate any output until tail generates 8K or so of output, so you might get the alert hours or days after the data occurs.

Comment: I'd use `...echo -e "\a" >&2...` so it doesn't have to pass through anything after this in the pipeline.

Comment: Ended up going with this as per @Carl's saying he liked this better.  Seems fine and does the job.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed to replace the key word with key word \a. That should work so long as your downstream steps don't mangle the \a.

Comment: Perfect solution.  Could you add a quick example of it?

Comment: eh.  I like +William Pursell's better.

Comment: sed seemed cleaner, but that's fine.  Went with William's.